# Cmd+Enter shortcut has stopped working in Atom Editor

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-elcapitan, atom-editor

The Cmd+Enter shortcut in Atom would usually cause the insertion of a new line beneath the current one and the caret to move to it. This stopped working for me a versions back though (I'm currently at 1.9.9), although Shift+Cmd+Enter still works (same, except the new line is inserted on the line above). I'm on OS X El Capitan.

Why has this shortcut stopped working, is it intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by the [tidalcycles](https://github.com/tidalcycles/atom-tidalcycles) package, which I figured out by bisection testing via [Package Cop](https://atom.io/packages/package-cop).